# list indices must be integers not str python error

Tags: python, string, list, integer, indices

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!

def average(numbers):
    total=sum(numbers)
    total= float(total)
    return total/len(numbers)

def get_average(student):
    homework=average(student["homework"])
    quizzes=average(student["quizzes"])
    tests=average(student["tests"])
    print student["name"]
    return .1*homework+.3*quizzes+.6*tests

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90: 
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80: return "B"
    elif score >= 70 : return "C"
    elif score >= 60 : return "D"
    else : return "F"

results=[] 

def get_class_average(students):
    results.append(get_average(students))
    return average(results)



qq=[lloyd,alice,tyler]


for x in qq:
    get_class_average(x)
    s= get_average(x)
    print s, get_letter_grade(s) 
    print

print results , "Total class average is %s" % average(results)
```

#

the above program although giving the correct result is giving me the following error:
get_class_average([alice]) resulted in an error: list indices must be integers, not str

The output is as follows:

```
Lloyd
Lloyd
80.55 B

Alice
Alice
91.15 A

Tyler
Tyler
79.9 C

[80.55, 91.14999999999999, 79.9] Total class average is 83.8666666667
None
```

Comment: I ran above code but it is working.  not getting `list indices must be integers, not str` exception.

Comment: How do you get the output if there is an error? Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: What's printing that error? Python does not normally report errors as "xxx resulted in an error..."

Comment: @Matthias . I am new to python and using codeacademy to learn it. I got the output and error in one of their practice exercises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is the average over all students, like:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    student_averages = list(get_average(student) for student in students)
    return average(student_averages)

get_class_average(qq)
```

Which outputs:

```
Lloyd
Alice
Tyler
83.86666666666666
```

So the problem is your implementation of `get_class_average`.

*Update*:

Your code can be simplified even more:

```
results = [get_average(student) for student in qq]
print results , "Total class average is %s" % average(results)
```

Comment: Looks good. `get_class_average` looks like it should be called with a list of students data as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Your way is much better and simpler but I wanted to understand my mistake. could you also explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @user3765371: You designed the function to take one student (a `dictionary`) as a parameter. When you call `get_class_average([alice])` the parameter is a `list` with one student.